# find executable paths to services

Tags: windows, server

Heloo,
Im trying to delete a folder from F drive and get a message that the action cannot be completed as the folder or a file within is used by a program. There are no programs running , my doubt is some of the services are using the file in the folder. Is there a way other than clicking on each services and looking at the executable path? I want a list of services that are using the F:\ in their executable. Please need help.
Thanks

Comment: Actually you want to find any program (including Explorer) that has a handle open in the folder. Lots of tools to find open files. But this is not a programming question.

Comment: Is your drive `F` special? Can you post the full path (could it be one of _Windows_ _special_ folders e.g. `System Volume Information`)? Typically there's no service that would keep it open; you might also check your apps (including the ones from `System Tray`), or your antivirus. Have you tried the good old _restart_ method that seems to be the answer to most of _Windows_ issues?

Answer (score 0):

All the unix tools will work e.g. Cygwin http://cygwin.com/

From a cygwin shell:

cd F:

rm -rf *

From the command line, Sysinternals suite includes Handle, that lists open handles. A few examples on how to use it:

Find all files opened from drive F:

c:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite>handle.exe |findstr /i F:\

Sysinternals 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Comment: Thanks John. Can you please tell me if rm removes the files in windows?

Comment: Yes I use it all the time on windows XP NOTE be careful f is for force and r is for recurssive (delete everything!).

Comment: Note that even if the _Cygwin_ approach might work for files, it doesn't for folders that have open handles.

Comment: chkdsk also to check for corruption